# break up touch event

Tags: javascript, touch, sencha-touch-2

let's say i have a following toggle.
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.field.Toggle

You can toggle by tapping, or by swiping.
if u don't let the screen go on swipe, and keep swiping with finger left-right,
the toggle keeps moving with your finger.
Is there a way to 'break' touch event?
Desired behaviour is i swipe, then if i keep swiping nothing happens, like
contact between finger and screen was lost.

What i did:
I can do it in toggle's scope - if i disable it on 'change', and enable back on 'touchend'. Not good, because i wanna do it for all toggles on screen while it's masked for example, and most of them, obviously, are not touched, so won't get touchend and enabled back

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add the toggle to an array on touchstart (on touchend you remove it from the array).
On masking you fire an event on the view, which runs through all items inside the array and 'break' the touch event.

Controller:

```
config: {
    refs: {
        view: '#my-view'
        toggles: '.togglefield'
    },
    control: {
        view: { maskstart: 'hereIBreakTouch'}
        toggles: {touchstart: 'hereIAddToggleToArray'
                  touchend: 'hereIRemoveToggleFromArray'}
    }
},
activeToggles: []

hereIBreakTouch: function() {
    // might want to loop
    var oActiveToggle = this.activeToggles[0];
    oActiveToggle.setEnabled(false);
    //oActiveToggel.fireEvent('touchend');
    Ext.defer(function() {oActiveToggle.setEnabled(true);}, 50, this);
}
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: great! except the question is how do i BREAK the touch, and 'hereIBreakTouch' is not a function :)

Comment: I added the function. I thought you wanted to do this yourself :) I did not test it, please let me know if it works.

Comment: Breaking touch means emulate like u lift finger from screen, so u can't change toggle with your finger anymore.What u did just fires the event, and u still can keep swiping toggle left/right if u didnt stop touching the screen

Comment: I changed my answer. Did you try to disable the toggle?